# S3 Bucket cannot be reached in GroundTruth Labeling

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-sagemaker, amazon-ground-truth

I am currently using GroundTruth Labeling, and have created a manifest file successfully. Right now, I am encountering the error "NetworkingError: Network Failure - The S3 bucket you entered in Input dataset location cannot be reached. Either the bucket does not exist, or you do not have permission to access it. If the bucket does not exist, update Input dataset location with a new S3 URI. If the bucket exists, give the IAM entity you are using to create this labeling job permission to read and write to this S3 bucket, and try your request again."

I have made the contents of the S3 bucket and the bucket itself public to everybody, so I was wondering why this error occurs.

Comment: You certainly should not have made the public. Revert that change and instead give the relevant IAM role proper S3 access permissions.

Comment: @luk2302 I am using the default SageMaker execution role permissions as shown in 4:02 of the tutorial link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_FPI6KjDlCI&t=217s . Somehow it still does not work.

Answer (score 0):

i don't know if you solved it already but it might have to do on which region you created the instance, if it was West (California) I think Sagemaker Groundtruth doesn't have resources there to do labeling jobs, try changing it to an eastern instance